# Filter Powershell object BY an Array

Tags: powershell

I have looked all over and I can only find examples of filtering an array by a single value, not an object by an array.

Here is what I have that works but seems kludgy to use a foreach loop, is there a way to filter my object by my array of "bad users"?

```
$permissions = dir -Recurse $path | where { $_.PsIsContainer } | ForEach-Object { $path1 = $_.fullname; Get-Acl $_.Fullname | ForEach-Object { $_.access }}         

$arrFilterDefaulsOut = @('NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM','BUILTIN\Administrators','BUILTIN\Users','CREATOR OWNER')
foreach ($filter in $arrFilterDefaulsOut) {
    $permissions = $permissions | Select-Object * | Where-Object -property IdentityReference -ne $filter 
}

$permissions | Select-Object *| Export-Csv $finalReport
```

I have tried using `-notcontains` but that seems to do nothing

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want as the end result. also what is `$_.access | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty '.\Application Data' -Value $path1 -passthru` for ? This is just attaching a property with name `.\Application Data` and value of the full path of the object to the access rules

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - yep, i just to have a column with the full path in addition - could call it FolderPath or something more logical i guess. don't need it for this example so i will edit to remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to filter out the defined identities, so you can do:

```
$permissionFiltered = $permissions | where-object {$arrFilterDefaulsOut -notcontains $_.IdentityReference}
```

Comment: WOW, I guess I just had the column and the filter array backwards this whole time! I tried so many things, but not that...I guess because I don't quite understand how that works

Comment: you want simply: myArray doesNotContain this value = ```$arrFilterDefaulsOut -notcontains $_.IdentityReference```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you were trying to do before with `Add-Member` before, this is how I would streamline the process keeping it efficient using an anonymous function that filters those [`FileSystemAccessRule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule?view=net-6.0) where `IdentityReference` is not in the `$arrFilterDefaulsOut` array and creates new objects from those rules adding the absolute path of the folders.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $path -Directory -PipelineVariable folder | & {
    begin {
        $arrFilterDefaulsOut = @(
            'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'
            'BUILTIN\Administrators'
            'BUILTIN\Users'
            'CREATOR OWNER'
        )
    }
    process {
        foreach($rule in (Get-Acl $_.FullName).Access) {
            if($rule.IdentityReference -notin $arrFilterDefaulsOut) {
                $rule | Select-Object @{ N='Path'; E={ $folder.FullName }}, *
            }
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv path\to\report.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: jepp... to stay with '-notcontains': ```$arrFilterDefaulsOut -notcontains $rule.IdentityReference```